# CSS split multiple divs with only one that scrolls

Tags: html, css, split

I am attempting to create a page with two divs, a left and right, and a third div along the bottom.

The goal is to have a photo in the left div and it be static. The right div will have smaller photos which scroll vertically. The third div, bottom, will be along the bottom and will be static as well.

---

|  left  | right scrolls |

---

### bottom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>text</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template go here -->


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

<body>
      <div class="element one">
        <h1>Text</h1>
        <img src="image.png" alt="Front View">
      </div>

      <div class="element two">
        <strong>Living Room</strong> 
        <img class="carousel_image" src="img/LivingRoom.png" alt="living room">

        <strong>Kitchen</strong> 
        <img class="carousel_image" src="img/Kitchen.png" alt="Kitchen">
        <img class="carousel_image" src="img/Kitchen2.png" alt="Kitchen Counter">
      </div>
<hr>
    <!-- bottom details / map -->
    <div class="container bottom">
      <!-- row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <strong>text</strong>
            <br>
            <strong>text</strong>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <strong>text</strong> 1984
            <br>
            <strong>text</strong> 0.20
          </div>
          <br><br><br><br>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Contact</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Make an Offer</a>
        </div><!-- /col -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Map</h3>
          <p>insert Google Map here</p>

       </div><!-- /col -->
      </div><!-- /row -->
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- ============================= -->
    <!-- All your JavaScript comes now -->
    <!-- ============================= -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JS -->

    <!-- Can place script tags with JavaScript files here -->

  </body>
</html>


div.element{
  width:60%;
  background-color: white;
  height:650px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

div.two{
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 60%;
}

.bottom{
  margin-top: 650px;
}

.carousel_image{
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}
```

Comment: the problem is? create fiddle please

Comment: Options below seem to be working @winresh24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this using simple `CSS` and a little bit of `Javascript` (jQuery alternative in js comments).

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnails')[0].style.height = document.getElementsByClassName('photo')[0].clientHeight+'px';

/*
  If you are using jQuery you can also use
  $('.thumbnails').css('height', $('.photo').height());
*/
```

```css
.row .photo{
  background: #ef4375;
} 

.row .thumbnails {
  background: #97b344;
  overflow-y: scroll;
} 

.row .footer {
  background: #febb39;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500/?text=Principal" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 thumbnails">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300/?text=Thumb 1" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300/?text=Thumb 2" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300/?text=Thumb 3" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300/?text=Thumb 4" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300/?text=Thumb 5" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So far so good, this seems to be working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kane I'm glad to hear that. If you think this is the solution to your answer then you can use the check mark (bellow up and downvote).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `add overflow-y:scroll;` to the div on the right.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I had overflow, but didn't have -y. It still didn't work, but I think the above bootstrap version may work!

Comment: Ah ok sorry couldn't help